# How to pass parameter from tMongoDBInput to tRestClient using Talend OS for Big Data

Tags: mongodb, talend, rest-client

I'm using Talend OS for Big Data and pulling data from HP ALM. It is working fine.
Here My Working Job Flow,

```
tFileInputProperties-->tContextLoad-->tMongoDBConnection-->tLibraryLoad-->tJava-->tRestClient-->tExtractXMLField-->tXMLMap-->tMongoDBOutput
```

Now, I'm trying to get the input like ALM URL, Credential, Req OR Defect OR tests column detail dynamically from mongoDB instead of property file component.

Is it possible to pass the value from mongoDBInput to tRestClient through the talend?

**Actual Result:**

```
"string" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
   <Entities TotalResults=\"518\">
   <Entity Type=\"defect\">
   <ChildrenCount>
   <Value>0</Value>
   </ChildrenCount>
   <Fields>
   <Field Name=\"detection-version\">
   <Value></Value>
   </Field>
   <Field Name=\"subject\"/>
   <Field Name=\"description\">
   <Value>&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;\ndescription9483\n&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field Name=\"priority\">
   <Value></Value></Field>
   <Field Name=\"project\">
   <Value></Value></Field>
   <Field Name=\"last-modified\"><Value>2018-08-31 13:05:59</Value></Field>
   </Entity><singleElementCollection>false</singleElementCollection>
   </Entities>"
```

**Expected Result:**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("596e69f9a2e6f23e28ba0d58"), 
    "summary" : "test duregesh", 
    "severity" : "2-Medium", 
    "priority" : "", 
    "status" : "", 
    "creation-time" : ISODate("2018-01-08T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "closing-date" : null, 
    "description" : "", 
    "owner" : "", 
    "id" : NumberInt(339)
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking about tMongoDBInput if you have only tMongoDBOutput in your job? Or I misunderstand your question (could you please be more explicit in this case)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. That is my existing working talend job. Now, I'm trying to pass the input value from tMongoDBInput instead of tFileInputProperties.

Comment: So what's the problem? You want to set context variable value from MongoDB using tMongoDBInput?

Comment: I have found the solution for this issue. Now,I'm trying to pull all the defect column data from ALM without specifying column names in tExtractXMLField Xpath mapping. Is it possible to do this?